# Function containing a process is returning a garbled value

Tags: function, powershell

Spent my whole morning trying to find where my return value was getting garbled. Now that I've finally found where, I still have no idea why. Function looks like this:

```
function Run-RemoteCommand {
param(...) # params are $Remote (host) $Command $Credentials $Quiet (optional switch)

    if($Quiet) {
       $Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
       $Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=$false
       $Process.StartInfo.Domain=$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
       $Process.StartInfo.UserName=$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().UserName
       $Process.StartInfo.Password=$Credentials.Password
       $Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle="Hidden"
       $Process.StartInfo.FileName=$PSExec
       $Process.StartInfo.Arguments=@("/acceptEULA",$Remote,"-s",$Command)
       $Process.Start()
       $Process.WaitForExit()
       $result = $Process.ExitCode
       return $result
    } else { 
       ... 
    }
 }
```

What's odd is that I can step through this in a debugger and watch everything work fine. The command runs, $result is filled with the return code, but the calling function receives True appended to the return code (eg True0 on success). I even tried overriding the return value and just saying

```
 return "false"
```

The calling function receives "Truefalse." All I can tell is that it's tied to $Process running. If I comment out $Process.Start(), the return code functions normally. Someone please save my sanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Process.Start() returns a boolean value which is True if it succeeds.  Remember that functions in PowerShell behave differently than standard programming languages.  PowerShell functions "return" or more technically correct "output" any command output that isn't captured by a variable or redirected to a file or Out-Null.  In this case change the Start line to:

```
[void]$Process.Start()
```

or

```
$Process.Start() | Out-Null
```

Check out [this blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/effective-powershell-item-7-understanding-output/) for a deeper explanation.

Comment: Thank you, Keith, now I don't have to spend all my money on Rogain to save the hair I was about to pull out! Good reading in that link, too. Espeically the part that applies here and starts "I’ve seen this problem bite folks time and time again on the PowerShell newsgroup..."